# "Waiting for network configuration" then no network for 5% of boots

Tags: boot, networking, network-manager

This doesn't occur very frequently. It did used to happen about 30% of the time, and then I opened the computer and found that the wifi PCI card wasn't screwed in properly. I did the screw up, and now it works correctly *almost always* (about 95% of the time). It annoys me when the computer starts without network capability, because I can't use it and it means I have to sit through another 103 seconds of reboot, like I did this afternoon.

I got a couple of photos today - the first one "Waiting for network configuration..." that lets me know that I'll have to wait for the process  to end and then reboot the computer when it's finished, and the second one "Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration...".

[image: Waiting for network configuration...]

[image: Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration...]

Comment: "...because I can't use it and it means I have to sit through another 103 seconds..."   You can't just manually restart networking or dhclient instead of rebooting?  `sudo service networking restart` ?

Comment: do you have network mounts in your /etc/fstab

Comment: @user4556274 I will try `sudo service networking restart` the next time it happens. Thanks.

Comment: My /etc/fstab:

`# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=c520dfe7-a7ac-4aa1-a1d4-f6c3f0c55165 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
` (1/2)

Comment: `# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=be80b30a-cddf-484d-821a-312a71d7027a none            swap    sw              0       0

# mount 4f721fc0-8072-453f-b48f-ca686bd89549=sdb1=InternalHDD at boot
UUID=4f721fc0-8072-453f-b48f-ca686bd89549 /mnt/InternalHDD               ext4    defaults 0       2` (2/2)

Comment: @user4556274 This bug happened again yesterday, so I took the opportunity to try what you suggested:

`el_gallo_azul@W2600CR-850Pro:~$ sudo service networking restart
[sudo] password for el_gallo_azul: 
stop: Job failed while stopping
start: Job is already running: networking
el_gallo_azul@W2600CR-850Pro:~$ 
`

As you can see, it was no help unfortunately. I find it amusing that I got the message `start: Job is already running: networking`, but Ubuntu had not found any "network configuration", and the network icon did not appear at the top right-hand side of the screen.

Comment: Jeez now I'm wondering if my wifi card has a screw loose. I remember some of the HDD or SSD in the laptop were missing screws and am psyching myself out the wifi card might be missing one altogether. Doesn't matter since I plugged spare 15' ethernet cable in between laptop and DSL cable modem/router do avoid dropped signal. Still thanks for bringing it up! ... Nothing worse than having a screw loose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has never occurred again since I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 ten days ago.

This is the first time that such an upgrade has worked successfully for me. Previous upgrade attempts, from 10.04 to 12.04, and 13.04 to 14.04, didn't work, and had to be followed up with installing from a freshly downloaded image, and then several hours of configuration of the system.

Comment: That would certainly be nice.

Yes, one would think that: (a) initially tightening the screw; **or** (b) successfully upgrading the operating system; would either be 100% or 0% successful, but they **both** seem to have contributed a little bit.

Comment: Yes. The intermittent nature of this error also led me to believe that it must be hardware-related. I hope it has ended forever.

Answer (score 3):

These messages appear while waiting for all interfaces marked as 'auto' in /etc/network/interfaces to come up. On most Ubuntu systems, that's only loopback (127.0.0.1); everything else is done later, via NetworkManager.

This usually happens if you've added something marked as both 'auto' and 'dhcp' in that file, and the DHCP server doesn't immediately respond. You'll see this screen until it does.

It might also happen if the device is "missing," for instance if the PCI card isn't seated properly and isn't recognized, or is defective.

So first, look in /etc/network/interfaces and determine what, aside from lo, is marked as auto (alternatively, use this command to print all the auto interfaces: `ifquery --list --allow auto`)

Probably, it'll just be your "wifi PCI card," but maybe it's another leftover device you're not using anymore? A wired Ethernet card with no cable plugged in? Remove the 'auto' from anything you don't want to come up at boot (and have to wait for).

If it is just your wireless card, did you mean to configure it this way instead of using NetworkManager? If not, I'd suggest the latter, especially for a wifi interface. Remove the 'auto' and reboot (or just run `ifdown [interface]` or even `ifdown -a`), log into the graphical desktop, and use the applet in your panel to set up the connection.

If you don't want to use NM for whatever reason, you probably still don't want to wait for the wireless at boot. In this case you'd remove the 'auto' again, and use the `ifup [interface]` command to bring it up later. To still do it automatically at boot (but not wait for it), ideally you would create your own upstart script in /etc/init that runs right after static-network-up. If you don't want to figure out how to do that, you could always just slap that command in /etc/rc.local, however.

`[interface]`, by the way, is probably going to be `wlan0`, but you should verify this by looking at the output of `ifconfig -a`, when it's working.

On to the actual failure, the next time it happens you're going to have to look at /var/log/syslog to find out exactly why. Since you say it works after you reboot, it's probably not going to be a DHCP server issue. More likely, it's an issue with the device. You might see lines like this:

> Aug 13 18:45:44 ubuntu dhclient: Error getting hardware address for "wlan0": No such device

Check to see whether the device even appears in the output of `ifconfig -a`. If it does, you can manually retry `ifup [interface]` (or just `ifup -a` if you never removed the autos) to see if it works without rebooting. If not, start looking at the kernel boot messages (`dmesg | less`) for anything relevant. Normally there's something printed when the device is first detected, for example:

> [   25.770930] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
>   [   25.770933] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
>   [   25.773887] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
>   ...
>   [   26.110349] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm

Look at your own when it's working to see what it should look like. Then, compare to when it's broken. Are there any errors? Or, is the wireless stuff missing altogether? That, to me, just screams poorly seated or defective card. Make very sure it is fully and firmly in the PCI slot.

If you found other kinds of errors, in syslog or in dmesg, you should probably file a bug. Save everything relevant you found in these logs and output of commands. When you are able to connect, run the command `ubuntu-bug networking` to create the bug, then attach whatever you saved.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan. I'll start to work through what you say at my earliest opportunity. I might have a chance to start later today.

Comment: I couldn't work out any way to leave a comment with legible formatting here, so I've written my comments into a pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/A9Ttz2i9

Comment: The error happened this morning when I booted, so I took the opportunity to `dmesg | less` http://pastebin.com/LXj4y0is and to get `/var/log/syslog` after the error message http://pastebin.com/RNx2Rsxu.

Comment: I compared a "successful boot" version of `syslog` with a "No network boot", and the same for two versions of `dmesg | less` output, and I'm none the wiser. I think it's time to give up. Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that tightening a screw has an impact on the frequency of the problem indicates (at least to me) that this is a hardware connectivity issue. I would remove the card, carefully clean the contacts on the card and replace it. If this doesn't resolve the problem It doesn't automatically indicate that the card is bad. Try the card in a different slot (or different system) as the slot could be defective, not the card.

Comment: Yes it seems that way to me, too @elder-geek. I re-seated the card yesterday after my post, and it hasn't made any difference (I had another “Waiting for network configuration” episode when I booted this morning). That indicates to me that it is time to move it to another PCI slot. I'll do that later today if I get an opportunity.

Comment: I've just taken the card out from one PCI slot and installed in another. I have only booted once so far, and it has worked so far (which is not conclusive either way).

Comment: @el_gallo_azul Best of luck.  Thank you for keeping us posted! :)

Comment: Sadly, it did the old "Waiting for network configuration..." routine, followed by no network, when I booted the computer this morning (about 7 hours ago).

It's normal for "Waiting for network configuration..." to appear during boot, but it usually disappears after a second or less.

I took a copy of `syslog` and `dmesg | less` again this morning when it failed, so if I get a chance I'll compare them to each other, and to these outputs from a successful boot (eg. the current one).

Comment: i would be suspicious of this card , if at all possible swap out for another identical card to isolate hardware issues. Paritial connection could have blown part of the electronics and occasional failure is good indicator of this. If the frequency of failure increases then bin the card , its dying.

Comment: @Amias If you agree with my assessment you can upvote the answer. Comments are generally used to request more information or suggest other improvements.

Comment: @el_gallo_azul If changing slots didn't resolve the issue and you can test the card in a different system you should do so. If that's not possible you can try replacing the card. You haven't indicated the age of the card/motherboard but one or the other is definitely failing.

Comment: Boo hoo. Yes, I might have to accept that the card is being a bit naughty. Unfortunately, I have no means to test it, and it's still better to reboot the computer (because of this error) than run an ethernet cable across the floor in two rooms. I'll probably live with it until the frequency of the error becomes unbearable.